# Testing $q$-binomial theorem at $z=1/a$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, q-analogs

The [$q$-binomial theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialTheorem.html) states that when $|q|<1$
$$ \frac{(az;q)_\infty}{(z;q)_\infty}={}_1 \phi_0 (a;\;;q;z)\equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}z^n \quad \text{for } |z|<1$$
with *no restriction* on $a$.
The proof can be found in Gasper & Rahman - *Basic hypergeometric series* or in Andrews, Askey, Roy - *Special functions*. 
Since there is no restriction on $a \in \mathbb{C}$, we can choose $a$ such that $|a|>1$.

My question is the following: the left-hand side of this equation has a *zero* at $z=a^{-1}$ since $(1,q)_\infty=(1-1)(1-q)\dots=0$, while the right-hand side is not obviously zero at $z=a^{-1}$. How are these two facts reconciled?

Comment: The domain and zeros of the RHS is far from being obvious if we don't have this formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a good observation and it is not obvious, but the following may be of interest to you.

If $z=1/a=q^k$ for some positive integer $k$, then 
$\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{(a;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}z^n = 0$ 
and also the terms of the summation for $n>k$ are zero because then $(a;q)_n=0$.

Perhaps this makes the identity more plausible for you.

Comment: I see. I suppose the finite sum is shown by induction and then the statement for $a\in \mathbb{C}$ follows by the identity theorem. So counter-intuitive as always, but great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @atabler Yes, good question. The result is similar to the usual binomial series $(1+z)^n$ where it is a finite sum if $n$ is an integer but a convergent infinite power series otherwise if $|z|<1$.

Comment: I have to add, my comment was not right: the identity theorem is not applicable here, as far as I can tell. I still don't know how to rigorously prove the statement, independently of the $q$-binomial theorem. Nevertheless Mathematica shows that the truncated sum $$\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(a;q)_n}{(q;q)_n} a^{-n} $$ is of order $\mathcal O ((a^{-1})^N)$  or higher thus in the limit one gets zero for $|a|>1$.

Comment: Let $f(a):=(a z;q)_\infty$ where $f(qa)(1-a)=f(a)$. Assume $f(a)/f(1) = 1+c_1z+c_2z^2+\dots$ Now show $f(a)/f(1)-f(aq)/f(q)=(1-a)f(aq)/f(1)$ and get a recursion for the series coefficients.